# How to remove extra entries from the tuple in apache pig

Tags: apache-pig

How do I solve the issue of extra comma or entries from the tuple

```
ab = load "/path/file1.txt" USING PigStorage(',') AS (id1:chararray, id2:chararray, dt:chararray, qty:int);
```

Current output:-
`(F1,S9,12/09/2011,2,,,)`

Expected Output:-
`(F1,S9,12/09/2011,2)`

Should I make changes in the text which is there in my file.txt or something else?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!!! Can You also share the Input file content. file.txt

Answer (score 0):

Write path between single quote('') in LOAD statement.

Example:

```
ab = load '/path/file1.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id1:chararray, id2:chararray, dt:chararray, qty:int);
```